# My write-to file keeps emptying after 2 kb

Tags: php

I am trying to save tokens to a php file using this code, but after 2kb the file mysteriously empties and I lose all the data. Why does this happen? how do I prevent it?

```
   $fh = fopen('token.txt', 'a+');
    fwrite($fh, $access_token . "\n");
    fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Do you really have to work with a file in append mode?  This has race-conditions written all over it.

Comment: I dunno about you, but I'd use memcached (or any database, for that matter) for this.

Answer (score 2):

As per comments elsewhere, using files to store data from multiple concurrent processes is a recipe for failure. You can minimise the damage (at the risk of introducing deadlocks and race conditions) by ensuring you get a valid flock() on the file before attempting to read or write from it.

```
$fh = fopen('token.txt', 'a');
if (flock($fh, LOCK_EX)) {
    fwrite($fh, $access_token . "\n");
    fflush($fh);
    flock($fh, LOCK_UN);
} else {
    trigger_error("failed to lock file");
}
fclose($fh);
```

If you're just logging then use the syslog facility. If you're performing the full set of CRUD operations, then use a DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas:

1. Multiple invocations of your PHP page are stomping over each other.  If two processes/threads open the same file for append simultaneously, I would not be surprised if the result is an empty file.
2. Change open mode from `a+` to `a`.  From your code it appears that you need only to write, not to read/write.
3. Check your filesystem available space (`df -h`) and your user's disk quota (`quota -h`).  Are you out of space?